# Trying to sum specific elements of a list with a "for i in range(len(list))" loop

Tags: python, list

```
list=[[10,12,22],[18,20,38],[32,35,67],[57,66,123],[103,121,224]]
```

This is the list that I am looping through.

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    print(f"The sum of every 3rd element within each sub list is {sum(list[i][2])}
```

When I run this, the error message is:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Is this simply not possible to do or am I making a stupid mistake?
I am quite new to coding so apologies for what may seem like a very stupid question to some.

Comment: Well first of all, this isn't an array but a list.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of correct language - I'm a school student and my teacher and exam board call them arrays for whatever reason. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: oh good opportunity to call the teacher out, then :D I'm sorry if this sounded condescending. The easiest way to solve this would be to define a result placeholder before the loop (e.g. `res = 0`) and then looping like `for element in mylist: res += element[2]`

Comment: Also, it is not a wise idea to name variables like built-in functions, rather use smth like `mylist` or if it has a real application, something meaningful

Comment: Not really. Your teachers are using a generic terminology valid in C, C++, ... - however, in python these things are called lists.

Comment: @atru Python has [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) *and* lists. This right here is a list

Comment: Yes, and tuples, and other containers and iterables :) However, in compiled languages things like lists were simply referred to as arrays. That's probably why their teachers and the exam board are calling them this way. Or maybe not. I catch myself doing that.

Comment: yeah ok I agree that this is nitpicky

Comment: Just trying not to completely discredit their teachers :D though they should use language-specific terminology... they really should... :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll help you out.  First don't use python keywords as a variable name - so `list` is not good.  Secondly I see so many people iterating over the range of the list and then referencing by index.  This isn't necessary.

```
l =[[10,12,22],[18,20,38],[32,35,67],[57,66,123],[103,121,224]]
```

## How I often see it done

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i][2])
```

## How it probably should be done

```
for x in l:
    print(x[2])
```

And the answer you are looking for:

```
sum(x[2] for x in l)
```

Comment: only pythonic answer here +1

Comment: Very clear and thank you for the other examples :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code gets 3rd integer of each i-th sub-array separately and can't sum int to itself. Here is right way to do this:

```
arr = [[10, 12, 22], [18, 20, 38], [32, 35, 67], [57, 66, 123], [103, 121, 224]]
s = 0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    s += arr[i][2]
print(f"The sum of every 3rd element within each sub array is {s}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you make a stupid mistake ;-). This: sum(list[i][2]) means you are summing over the second element over the list[i] which is an int. And this is not iterable.
Using a list comprehension this does the trick

```
print(f"The sum of every 3rd {sum([j[2] for j in list])}")
```

Comment: You can remove the `[]` brackets in the `sum`, which effectively makes this the same as @Chris answer

Comment: Sure, thanks. I was not aware  that Chris had already answered the question.